# Replace colored background with gradient background for flutter app depending on dark / light mode

Tags: flutter, background, gradient

I would like to change the standard theme background colors of my flutter app to gradient background, depending on dark / light mode. so that the light mode shows a different gradient like the dark mode. I managed to do it with a container and decoration, it was broken down into individual pages with sometimes more and sometimes less satisfactory results, as this only covers the background and as a result the app no ​​longer runs completely smoothly. So I thought the correct way would have to be to integrate it via the snappy normal background, but unfortunately I have absolutely no idea whether this is even possible ...

this is an excerpt from my main.dart

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isDark = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;
    return Padding(
      child: MaterialApp(
        locale: _getLocale(),
        navigatorKey: Magazin.navKey,
        title: Config.appTitle,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          brightness: _brightness,
          canvasColor: _brightness == Brightness.dark
              ? Color(0xFF282C39)
              : Color(0xFF565A67),
          primaryColor: _brightness == Brightness.dark
              ? Color(0xFF1B1E28)
              : Color(0xFF34445c),
        ),
```

I thought I could somehow modify it from this code, but I think I'm not really right with that, I hope I've mentioned everything important. I'm also not really sure whether there is a simple solution that fits the code for a newcomer, .... thank you for reading the article :-)

```
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      stops: [0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 1],
                      colors: [Colors.black12, Colors.grey, Colors.black54, Colors.black45])
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could embed your `Scaffold` inside a `Container` defining the gradient?

[image]

Remember to define the `backgroundColor` of your `Scaffold` as `Colors.transparent`.

### Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class AppLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const AppLayout({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          stops: [0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 1],
          colors: [Colors.black12, Colors.grey, Colors.black54, Colors.black45],
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppLayout(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Hello, GHOST!',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 48,
            color: Colors.white70,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the idea, so i had it except for the transparent in the scaffoldals, the transparent one fixed a few errors, but the result is unfortunately not really the desired one. in addition, when switching to the settings page, an error occurs, which leads to a crash. I think it won't be that easy ^^ would like to achieve in the end that the color of the gradient changes in dark and light mode. But the tip with the transparent was something that I could certainly need again at some point

Comment: Oh, sorry it does not help you more. Could you provide a Minimal, Complete, Reproducible code sample. That would help people answer your question.

Comment: gladly .. could you special was you exactly or do you judge directional? This means that the relevance that has been given am but a novice and its that I am not really that much yet... 
By the way, I had to smile about the "hello ghost" ^^ 